# Why my progressDialog never ends?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I have a `MainActivity` class in my Android project. Inside of it, I have an `AsyncTask` to retrieve all the information about my `Cars` with a `GET` method of my API REST and I want to add them to an ArrayList that I have in my `MainActivity` class. Because of that, I wanted to add a `ProgressDialog` that finish at the same time that my AsyncTask finish.

I have declared my ProgressDialog on the top of my MainActivity:

```
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
```

And also, my `ArrayList` of cars it's defined on the top of my `MainActivity`:

```
ArrayList<Car> cars = new ArrayList<Car>(); //This is the ArrayList that I have on my MainActivity class
```

Then, I run my `AsyncTask` and initialize my `ProgressDialog` in the `onCreate` method of my `MainActivity` class:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
        progressDialog.setMax(100);

        new chargeCars().execute();
    }
```

And here it's my AsyncTask:

```
class chargeCars extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Boolean> {

    protected void onPreExecute(){
        progressDialog.setProgress(0);
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {

        //Here all the code to get my information from an HTTP Response, the data it's retrieving OK.

           //Here there is a for loop to add all the elements to my ArrayList cars.
            {
                cars.add(new Car(idCar, model));

                publishProgress(10);

                if(isCancelled())
                    break;
            }

        publishProgress(100);
        return true;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values){
        int progress = values[0].intValue();

        progressDialog.setProgress(progress);
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(boolean c){

        if(c)
        {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Finished task!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        if(progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()){
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    protected void onCancelled() {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Canceled task",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

The problem it's that the `ProgressDialog` never ends, it's always on the screen. Why it is always displaying? Is my AsyncTask always running? Never ends?

**Note:** The information of my HTTP response it's coming well from my API REST because I put some logs after I retrieve the information and it is correct and apparently it is stored in the `ArrayList` (I put some logs too after add the information to my `ArrayList` and it gives me the information stored) but when I put `cars.size()` after executing my `AsyncTask` on the `onCreate()` method it gives to me that the size it's equals to 0. It's the reason that I put my `ProgressDialog` inside of my `AsyncTask`, because I think it maybe didn't finished yet and then I'm secure that the AsyncTask has finished. Could it be the solution? Have I to make another change?

Please bring me light because I'm totally block here.

**EDIT:** I edited my code.

**EIDT 2:** With the code updated the ProgressDialog only disappears when I touch the screen of my mobile phone. In other cases it doesn't disappear.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In your onPostExecute add,

```
if(progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()){
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
```

Comment: It is also executing itself all the time, never ends. Why it could be?

Answer (score 0):

use the [`dismiss()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#dismiss()) method!

```
  @override
   protected void onPostExecute(boolean c){

            if(c)
            {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Finished task!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
           if(progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()){
                 progressDialog.dismiss();
           }
        }
```

> **dismiss ()**
>
> Added in API level 1 Dismiss this dialog, removing it from the screen.
>   This method can be invoked safely from any thread. Note that you
>   should not override this method to do cleanup when the dialog is
>   dismissed, instead implement that in onStop().

Comment: I added as `Jayesh Elamgodil` said to me but it also didn't work. What could be the problem?

Comment: hey ! I think you are missing the @override for the methids of the AsyncTask.

Comment: And what its the difference to use @overrride or not?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your methods `onPause` and `onDestroy` in your `AsyncTask` do not override anything in the class and are therefore never called. If you need something done when the `AsyncTask` is finished, you put it in the method `onPostExecute` (which runs on the UI thread). You should remove these two methods (since they're useless) and set your onPostExecute method as follows:

```
protected void onPostExecute(boolean c){
    if(c) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Finished task!",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    if(progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()){
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

See the [Android docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for methods available in `AsyncTask`

Comment: I have some doubts. What exactly do you mean when you say that `do not override anything`. What does it mean override? (Sorry if it is an obvius question). And the other doubt, I have another AsyncTask running before this that sets the values on a CustomAdapter that shows the values in a list. Before (with onPause and onDestroy methods) it doesn't appear, now it appears. But the ProgressDialog it's still show and the information of the second AsyncTask doesn't appear. It is possible that the first AsyncTask block the second one? Thank you!